# How to Parse a FCPXML file using C# XML Deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'd like to parse a FCPXML file using C#. The [DTD is available](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FinalCutProX/Reference/FinalCutProXXMLFormat/FCPXMLDTD/FCPXMLDTD.html). To start, I opened the DTD in Visual Studio 2017 and exported it as an XSD using the menu bar item `XML->Create Schema`. In this particular case, the DTD version above is missing the `info-asc-cdl` element and you have to patch it in from [version 1.1 of the DTD](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/LegacyDTDsFinalCutPro/FCPXMLDTDv1.1/FCPXMLDTDv1.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014172-CH19-SW1).

Then I ran:

```
"c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/bin/NETFX 4.0 Tools/x64/xsd.exe" ..\..\FcpXml\xsd\fcpxml1p8.xsd /classes /outputdir:..\..\FcpXml /namespace:LibTimeline.FcpXml
```

...from the build directory.

When I attempt to deserialize using the following code:

```
  var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(fcpxml));

  using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
  {
    fcp = (fcpxml)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
  }
```

I get the exception, `InvalidOperationException: <fcpxml xmlns=''> was not expected.` That kinda makes sense since the generated XSD specifes the targetNamespace as `http://tempuri.org/fcpxml1p8`:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://tempuri.org/fcpxml1p8" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/fcpxml1p8" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="fcpxml">
```

However, the actual XML file I'm parsing doesn't specify a namespace for the root node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE fcpxml>
<fcpxml version="1.8">
    <resources>
        <format width="1920" id="r0" frameDuration="1001/30000s" height="1080" name="FFVideoFormat1080p2997"/>
```

What's the recommended way of dealing with this? I'd like to continue using C# XML Deserialization if at all possible. The `DTD -> XSD -> C#` flow is really nice. I can't really change the input files on disk since they're generated by third-party tools (Final Cut Pro, DaVinci, Premiere, etc.). I suppose I could edit the XML once it's loaded into memory.

Note that I have tried specifying the root node in my C# using the following code:

```
  var xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = "fcpxml", IsNullable = false };
  var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(fcpxml), xRoot);
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
  {
    fcp = (fcpxml)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
  }
```

This allows me to deserialize the root node (and its attributes) without exceptions, but none of the child nodes get deserialized. I believe this is because they don't have the expected namespace.

Comment: Can you control the URI when invoking xsd.exe?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe

Comment: @MikeJ, yes. I can manually edit it.

Comment: look at the args to xsd.exe, can't you control the two attributes you're removing in the answer below?

Comment: If you know the argument that does it, please share it. I looked for one while writing the answer and I didn't see anything that fit that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the following two attributes from the generated XSD file's root element:

```
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/fcpxml1p8"
targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/fcpxml1p8"
```

...and regenerate the classes, it will deserialize the full structure, and you don't have to include the `xRoot` argument.

```cs
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(fcpxml));
using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    doc = (fcpxml)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried what you suggested and set `xmlns` and `targetNamespace` to empty strings in the generated XSD's root element. I can now deserialize. Thanks! I presume this is best practice for my situation...

Comment: OK. Removing the attributes entirely is what you proposed. That works fine too.

Comment: Setting them to empty strings gave me warnings in the editor saying that they can't be empty; that's why I removed them. If empty strings work for you and that's what you prefer, more power to you. That's what the namespace ends up being anyway when those attributes are absent.

Comment: Since the XSD file should only need to be generated once and what was generated was not correct, patching those attributes after generation is safe (but document what you did in case you have to regenerate the XSD for 1.9!). This is probably about as "best" as it will get for this situation. If you had to regenerate regularly, I'd suggest writing a small utility that post-processes the file so it's done consistently every time.

Comment: Doesn't the xsd.exe allow you to correctly set those to begin with?

Comment: I don't believe so. The XSD was generated using the menu item XML > Create Schema, which generated the XSD using just the DTD that was opened in the editor as the input, so it synthesized those attributes using tempuri.org and the base file name (for the path). xsd.exe has a `/namespace:` switch but it specifies the namespace of the classes to be generated. I didn't see a way to override the `xmlns` and `targetNamespace` attribute values from the input schema on the command line with xsd.exe.

Comment: I know that editing the schema seems like a bit of a hack, but you also have to consider the source: it's not an official XSD. It's based on the official DTD, but DTD is limited and, as far as I know, it doesn't have any concept of namespaces. I assume this will be a rare action to have to take, so as long as the manual steps -- 1) patching in the `info-asc-cdl` element definition from an older version, and 2) fixing the target namespace --  are documented, a regression will be easy enough to avoid next time. And hopefully, the `info-asc-cdl` problem will be fixed and that step can be removed.